¿Como manipular los servicios locales con c#?
Estoy realizando una aplicación donde requiero detener el servicio de Theams pero cuando lo quiero detener me sale un error.
Lo hago de la siguiente manera:
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serverName = "Temas";
        string localMachine = Environment.MachineName;

        if (Operations.ServiceExists(serverName))
        {
            // Crear una instancia de ServiceController para el servicio
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serverName);
            sc.MachineName = localMachine;

            // Verificar el estado actual del servicio
            if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                // Iniciar el servicio si está detenido
                MessageBox.Show($"Iniciando el servicio '{serverName}'...");
                sc.Start();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                MessageBox.Show($"El servicio '{serverName}' se ha iniciado correctamente.");
            }
            else if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                // Detener el servicio si está en ejecución
                MessageBox.Show($"Deteniendo el servicio '{serverName}'...");
                sc.Stop();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                MessageBox.Show($"El servicio '{serverName}' se ha detenido correctamente.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"El servicio '{serverName}' no se puede iniciar o detener en su estado actual.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"El servicio '{serverName}' no existe.");
        }
    }

y el error que me arroja es el siguiente:

Al principío pensé que era por el nombre de la maquina, ya se lo agregue pero me sigue mandando el mismo error, espero me puedan apoyar a poder ver mi error.

Lo que estuve investigando es que era tema de permisos y lo resolví de la siguiente manera:
1- Agregué el siguiente archivo 
2- En la configuración coloque la siguiente <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
